# Need more memory-efficient method of filtering vector of date values

Tags: r, datetime, vector, memory-management, filter

Total newbie to R here (so far very pleased!).

I have a large array(vector?) of date information, and I would like to remove the rows that do not fit within an my date range of interest (which is 24-sept-2003 to 10-december-2003, from 12pm to 6pm each day). I seem to be running out of memory

Here's an example of the issue as well as I can put it:

```
> head(p_times)
[1] "2001-04-11 07:57:27 EDT" "2001-04-11 08:18:11 EDT"
[3] "2001-04-11 08:21:33 EDT" "2001-04-11 08:22:52 EDT"
[5] "2001-04-11 08:25:39 EDT" "2001-04-11 08:31:18 EDT"
> length(p_times)
[1] 31164014
> class(p_times)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
> fp_times = p_times[p_times$year==103]
R(59593,0xa0506540) malloc: *** mmap(size=249315328) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(59593,0xa0506540) malloc: *** mmap(size=124657664) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(59593,0xa0506540) malloc: *** mmap(size=57901056) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I was planning to filter by year to remove most of the information, and then using the same approach to filter by month / day / hour

Comment: One hacky workaround is (assuming your input file is sorted by date, if it isn't then sort it), to just figure out which start and end row(s) you want and use those in `read.csv()`. Also object.size of POSIXlt > POSIXct > as.integer(POSIXlt)

Comment: Hey when you wrote `class(p_times) = "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`, is that "POSIXt" a typo? If not, that could explain weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use `POSIXct` instead of `POSIXlt`?  `POSIXlt` objects seem to take ~5x more memory than `POSIXct` objects:

```
> set.seed(21)
> x <- Sys.time() - trunc(runif(31164014)*3e8); range(x)
[1] "2001-12-03 11:55:25 CST" "2011-06-06 18:15:07 CDT"
> print(object.size(x), units="Mb")
237.8 Mb
> print(object.size(as.POSIXlt(x)), units="Mb")
1188.8 Mb
> 1188.8/237.8
[1] 4.999159
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't actually know if I can, but I'll look into it. I could always represent it as ct, and convert it into lt inside of the index access

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Joshua's answer: `POSIXlt` records much more information so you can use, for example, `$year`. `POSIXct` on the other hand counts only the seconds since the UNIX epoch. So `POSIXct` is smaller but with less convenience. But you could still filter with this if you calculate the relevant times:

```
start <- unclass(as.POSIXct("2003-09-24"))-unclass(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"))
end <- unclass(as.POSIXct("2003-12-11"))-unclass(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"))

p_times <- as.POSIXct(p_times)
fp_times <- p_times[p_times>start & p_times<end]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was actually 1/2 of the solution I used after I read Joshua's soln. :p